# Java: method takes varargs of unrelated types

Tags: java, scala, type-systems

I have a Java factory method with a varargs array of `Object`s at the end.  The array can contain any combination of `String`s and `ScaledJpeg`s.  The theory being that an HTML table cell can contain any number of text nodes or `<image>` nodes and it will line-wrap the images as though they were just funny-shaped words.

```
// constructor
public Cell(TextStyle ts, float w, CellStyle cs, Object... r) {
    if (w < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("A cell cannot have a negative width");
    }
    if (r != null) {
        for (Object o : r) {
            if ( (o != null) &&
                 !(o instanceof String) &&
                 !(o instanceof ScaledJpeg) ) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(INVALID_ROW_TYPE_STR);
            }
        }
    }
    textStyle = ts; width = w; cellStyle = cs; rows = r;
    avgCharsForWidth = (int) ((width * 1220) / textStyle.avgCharWidth());
}
```

In Scala, I might use a list of `Either[String,ScaledJpeg]`.  But some day I'll probably make this method allow something else, say another nested `Cell`, but doing so would break existing code that only expected two possible types.  At least the way it is, future changes won't break existing code.

The current solution works, allows for expansion, and is relatively easy to use, except that it defeats type safety and can only throw an exception at runtime if someone passes something unexpected as a vararg.  For instance, I just forgot to add `toString()` to a `StringBuilder` and it blew up at runtime.  So already that's a third class to account for (Since `toString()` is defined on every object, I don't want to call it on whatever is passed because doing so for most object types would be an error much further down in the code violating the fail-fast behavior of this example).

`java.lang.String` can't implement any new interfaces and that's probably a good thing.  Even if I could make a wrapper class, everything about the way text and images are treated by this class is completely different *except* that they are line-wrapped together the way they would be in HTML (or in a Word doc).

As I write this, it occurs to me that I should probably use a Builder pattern, make a `CellBuilder` class that has `addText()` and `addImage()` methods that does away with the varargs constructor.  This would encapsulate the underlying List in a way that the user of the API gets 100% compile-time type safety.  But out of curiosity, I'm still posting this in case there are other creative and possibly better solutions out there.

Comment: When you need arbitrary arguments of specific types, a [builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is the way to go as you mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a `Row` interface with two implementations:  one for images and one for strings.  Then your `Cell` constructor takes a `Row... r`.  This lets the compiler verify your types, and keeps you from having `if image... else if string...` all over the place.  Adding a new type is simple, just create another implementation.  If you need a new method in the interface, your compiler ensures all your implementations have it.

Comment: You mean like a wrapper class, only an interface that can hold either a `String` or a `ScaledJpeg` thus: `new Cell(ts, w, cs, Wrapper.of("hello"), Wrapper.of(myScaledJpg), Wrapper.of("world"))`

Comment: No, not just a wrapper.  You have other places in your `Cell` class that do things like `if (rows[0] instanceof String) renderString((String)rows[0]); else if (rows[0]) instanceof ScaledJpeg) renderJpeg((ScaledJpeg)rows[0]);`.  Instead you want a `StringRow` class and a `JpegRow` class that each implement a `render()` method of the `Row` interface.

Comment: Making a hierarchy of types as you and @Daenyth suggest might be the best general solution to this kind of problem.  But doing so makes the API user think they could pass anything that implements that interface to the Cell constructor.  That's just not possible in this situation due to line-wrapping strings and passing them and images separately to an underlying 3rd party API: https://github.com/GlenKPeterson/PdfLayoutManager/blob/master/src/main/java/com/planbase/pdf/layoutmanager/Cell.java  I think the Builder pattern is most appropriate here.  Thank you both for your help!

Comment: I take it back, you may be right...  I'll think more, but don't waste your time on this.

Comment: But they *can* pass anything that implements the interface if you design the interface correctly.  I only gave it a cursory look, but I think an interface with something like `Row[] lineBreak(width)`, `getHeight()`, and `draw(pby)` methods would work quite well.

Comment: I did as you suggested and created a Renderable interface.  It required major refactoring to apply in this particular example, but is a very good solution.  There are still some things I'd like hidden that are exposed and vice-versa, but until I can articulate them, it's good enough.

Answer (score 2):

Since you assign `rows = r` and `r: Array[Object]`, I'd use this approach:

```
sealed trait HasRow {
  def row: Object
}

class StringRow(s: String) extends HasRow {
  override def row = s // or some logic
}

class JpegRow(j: ScaledJpeg) extends HasRow {
  override def row = j // or some logic
}

class Cell(ts: TextStyle, w: Float, cs: CellStyle, r: HasRow*) {
 // ...
}
```

As you mention, a builder style approach is also possible and might be better.